# Rapidshare File Uploader

Tags: javascript, file, upload, rapidshare

Anybody knows how multifile uploader in rapidshare is implemented? I'm telling about multiple selecting of files:
[image: Selecting multiple files]

And separating them per file upload progress:
[image: Multi upload progress]

I didn't see nginx uploadprogress calls (like in depositfiles) or any other, so RS may use ajax upload. I read that old IE's can't use crossdomain ajax upload, but RS working perfect in IE7-IE9. RS uploader working in all browsers. I turned off Java and Flash in browser, but RS uploader still working. How???

Comment: Do you mean turning off Javascript rather than Java? How are you testing ie7-9. More to the point, why are you bothered? Do you want to replicate this for your own site or create a UI for rapidshare?

Comment: 1. No. I mean Java is turned off, not Javascript. Javascript is turned on.
2. I opened IE7-9 and watch a traffic that comes from browser, used debugger.
3. Yes I want to replicate this functional to my site.

Answer (score 1):

Modern (non-IE) browsers have a new file API. Along with the multiple attribute on `input type=file` elements, you can read a couple of files and upload them seperatly.

Here is a basic of examples of this new feature:

```
file.onchange = function()
{
    if(file.files.length)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            // do something with e.target.result;
        };

        //reader.readAsBinaryString(file.files[0]);
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Also see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader).

In Internet Explorer (pre 9), this is probably an ActiveX feature. It should not work with the default settings in IE 8, however.

You can look this up with the term `new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");`.

Comment: Hmmm... I missed that. Thank you for this link. I found more detail explanation of this feature:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications